# When Submitting transaction from fabric client application, from which peer SDK will actually submits transaction to the network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

Im going through Hyperledger Fabric web App development.Im still confused with fabcar nodejs example where chaincode is deployed on first-network( total of 4 peers). After we run `startFabric.sh` we are able to query or submit transactions with `query.js or invoke.js`. while doing so, we are communicating with network via Fabric node SDK. for example, if we try to change car owner, we simply modify `invoke.js` with this function and run `node invoke.js` then it will simply change particular car owner in the ledger. Here my question is, we have 4 peers where our chaincode is currently installed, from which peer SDK will actually submits transaction to the network?. What if we wanted to submit transaction from another peer?? How can we define connecting peer(transaction submitting peer) in `invoke.js` any clarification??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things need to clarify..

When you submit a transaction from SDK Client, it will go to endorsing peers for endorsement purpose and it will return back to the client and with endorsement result & actual payload it will connect to the orderer

I hope you are using `fabcar/javascript-low-level`

You can mention which peers it need to send Tx from a client in the below targets

**Note**: this is just to understand about peer by the client, when you send it will go to all endorsing peers. (Initiate req by client)

Actually you shouldn't care about it Try **gateway service**

```
    const proposal_request = {
        targets: [peer],
        chaincodeId: 'fabcar',
        fcn: 'createCar',
        args: ['CAR12', 'Honda', 'Accord', 'Black', 'Tom'],
        chainId: 'mychannel',
        txId: tx_id
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Narendranath Reddy. So, you mean that " Transaction went through all endorsing peers instead of of single peer and then result is validated  by orderer. Right?? I think, gateway will connect to the entire organization specified in connection profile and submits transaction to endorsers?? Am I right??

Comment: yes, orderer will not validate as endorsing peers are there to validate the transaction. Yes, the gateway is meant for that.

Comment: Yeah. I mean after transaction is executed on endorsing peers, the response will be sends to orderer and response will be validated and orders into the block. Suppose if we send an invocation to change value, in this case wether endorsing peers update the ledger since chaincode will be executed on these peers or orderer updates the ledger as it validate blocks and order them on network,??

Comment: Endorsing peers will not update the ledger as it will simulate it and send back the simulation results to the client and once orderer sends the block to committing peers these peers validate and update the ledger and world state. Note: endorsing peers are also commiting peers!!